# How to access a private nexus repo to install npm package?

Tags: npm, nexus

I have a private package sitting in a nexus repo which is authenticated, I want to install that package as a dependency in my local project, I have the username and password for the nexus repo, how do I do it through npm

I tried setting my local machine's npm registry to the nexus repo url but I got unauthorised error which makes sense because it is authenticated. Need help

Comment: What version of NXRM is this for?

Comment: 2.14.4-03 is the version

Comment: Can you include your .npmrc?  Make sure to obfuscate any username/password.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69388273/nexus-repo-npm-install-errorconnreset

can you look into this issue as well.